# Can not access ubuntu server with SSH after resetting firewall

Tags: firewall, putty

I'm desperate at the moment, but I will try to be as clear as possible.

I use Putty to access a server with Ubuntu installed on it, I wanted to make the firewall allow the access only to some IP. I was following a guide but at a certain point I wrote `sudo ufw reset`. After that everything stopped working, I can't access my server anymore because everytime I try Putty drop the "Connection timed out" error, I've also tried to log on WinSCP, but it can't connect too, and if I try to enter the site the browser says that it took too long to acces the site.

I've tried to do `ping mystite_IP`, it works perfectly. I don't know if I need to say other informations, ask eventually. Please help me.

Comment: You need to get console or pseudo console access - you wpuld need to speak to your provider to find their mechanism for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will need either physical access to your machine to gain console access and change the firewall rules but you won't be able to connect from the outside if your firewall doesn't allow it.

If your computer is not physically accessible, your hosting company might provide some interface that will let you connect to your machine, an example is the [IPMI console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface) (sometimes also called KVM interface for Keyboard Video and Mouse).